# Clone a Githubenterprise Repo using python libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github, github3.py

I am using github3.py library for my remaining code modules.
So if possible can we use github3.py lib for cloning a repo or any other python library is also good.

Comment: under linux or windows??

Comment: I am using a mac. but after running the python code it can be run in any operating system only if we are using python inbuilt libraries else if we are running the terminal commands from python script then it can be dependent on the operating system right?
Else it is operating system independent.

Comment: And with import subprocess ?

Comment: with import subprocess I am able to clone but I want through the python libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you should be able to clone it the same way as a normal repository.

Comment: Actually I am not able to as it throws an error that it is not able to find link.
fatal: unable to look up git@github.company.com:myusername (port 9418) (nodename nor servname provided, or not known)'